# Is OpenCV HoughLines using this paper: Real-Time Line Detection Through an Improved Hough Transform Voting Scheme"

Tags: opencv, hough-transform

today I found this paper "Real-Time Line Detection Through an Improved Hough Transform Voting Scheme" from here http://www2.ic.uff.br/~laffernandes/projects/kht/. This one is published on 2007 so I just wonder if opencv is using it or not? If not, then why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a random computer vision paper on the internet, assume it's not implemented in openCV. This has mostly to do with limited time of the contributors of openCV.

I do see that they provide the source code (both in mathlab and C++), so it should not be that difficult to implement it in openCV.

Comment: I know it's not difficult to implement. I just wondered if this one is good enough to be implemented by opencv (because it has been published for a long time). And because I didn't see that, I want to know why. The contributors don't know about it? It not so good?

Comment: Check the implementation they provide to see how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Source code](https://github.com/laffernandes/kht) of  this paper in C++, Matlab and Python.